# Como recorrer un arreglo que se manda desde php a Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Bueno haciendo esta ajax que mando a un formulario de procesa el cual me devuelve un Arreglo que traen parametros y un arreglo de nombres dejaré aquí mi ejemplo de código php;

este es un arreglo de nombres el cual lleno con un for que hago

```
$nombre[]= $nuevoNombre; 

    $respuesta=array('IdImagen'=>$nextID,'Nombre'=>$nombre,'error'=>$dpError);
          $dpResult= json_encode($respuesta);
          echo $dpResult;


    $.ajax({


        cache: false,
        url:ruta,
        type:"POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(respuesta){
        var res = new String(respuesta.Nombre);
        for (x=0; x< res.length ;x++){
        var strHTML = "<img src='media/thumbs/" +res.replace(/,/g,"")[x]+ "' width='100' height='100' alt=''>";
        }
        alert(strHTML);
    }
    });
```

y cuando lo imprimo en el alert me devuelve esto

```
<img src='media/thumbs/153.jpeg154.jpeg155.jpeg' width='100' height='100' alt=''>
```

y quisiera saber si es posible que pudiera salir así

```
<img src='media/thumbs/153.jpeg width='100' height='100' alt=''>
<img src='media/thumbs/154.jpeg width='100' height='100' alt=''>
<img src='media/thumbs/154.jpeg width='100' height='100' alt=''>
```

Para así poder mostrar unas preview de fotos que e subido!

Espero su ayuda y que aya sido claro en lo que pido Graciaaaaaas!

Comment: podria editar la pregunta y colocar unam muestra de coo esta conformado el retorno del php que imagino es un json, pues creo que es alli donde esta el problema, esto debido a que si estuviera bien estructurado, no tendrias que estar haciendo replaces ni nadea de eso solo sería : `res[x]` en todo caso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema se debe a que no estas concatenando las cadenas, sino que siempre estas pisando el valor asignado en cada vuelta del bucle.

### Solución:

- Debe definir la variable `strHTML` fuera del bucle `for`.
- Para concatenar puedes usar:

  - El [operador de adición](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Assignment_Operators#Asignaci%C3%B3n_de_Adicci%C3%B3n) (`+=`). Ejemplo:

    ```
    var strHTML = "";
    for (x=0; x< res.length ;x++) {
      strHTML += 'string';
    }
    alert(strHTML);
    ```
  - Pisar valor agregando el valor anterior. Ejemplo:

    ```
    var strHTML = "";
    for (x=0; x< res.length ;x++) {
      strHTML = strHTML + 'string';
    }
    alert(strHTML);
    ```
  - Un arreglo, [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push) para agregarlos y luego [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join) para generar el resultado. Ejemplo:

    ```
    var strHTML = [];
    for (x=0; x< res.length ;x++) {
      strHTML.push('string');
    }
    alert(strHTML.join(''));
    ```
  - Etc.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, me solucionó mi problema, utilizando el literal 3, Solo cambiandole que el arreglo lo recorriera desde el punto 1 porque el cero venia vacío, y concatenando en  el push la posción `strHTML.push('string[x]');`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un `for in` para recorrer un arreglo de la siguiente forma;

```js
 var res = {"nombres":"John"};
 var strHTML = "";
 for (var nombres  in res ){
    strHTML += "<img src='media/thumbs/" +res['nombres']+ "' width='100' height='100' alt=''>";
    console.log(strHTML);
}
```

Donde `res` es tu arreglo y `nombres` es tu variable local en el `for in`

Puedes obtener mas informacion en la documentacion : https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo mas comodo seria que utilizases el formato json para pasar la respuesta del php al js.

-Esto seria poniendo en el archivo php la siguiente linea:

```
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

`$resultado` es el array que contiene las respuestas.

-Y lo reconvirtieses a array en el archivo js con el siguiente comando:

```
var resp = JSON.parse(respuesta);
```

`respuesta` es la variable que recibes de php.

Una vez hecho esto ya puedes usarlo como un array normal e ir sacando cada valor.